# How can I have Jalali calendar or Jalali Date Picker in Kendo UI?

Tags: calendar, datepicker, kendo-ui, persian

I need Jalali calendar (Persian calendar) or Jalali date picker with kendo UI, But I don't know how can I have it?

Answer (score 4):

Kendo UI currently supports only the Gregorian calendar. Persian calendar is not supported.

Comment: for datetimepicker doesn't exist any library for jalali (persian) calendar. but for datepicker or timepicker for ver 2016 available in google results.

Answer (score 2):

Kendo UI do not support Persian calendar but there is a Persian date picker that is built on top of KendoUI libraries. [Here](http://www.alirezazahedi.com/?p=337) you can use it.

[image]